# Kendo UI for Angular2 - ContextMenu

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I just would like to know if you are going to release ContextMenu for Angular 2...and when.....

we have just to decide if use external library or Kendo for our product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI for Angular 2 PM here. A Context Menu component is a must; it is necessary building block for the more complex components. However, one is unlikely to be available in the next couple of months, so you may look around for alternatives in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks Petyo for response. I just would like to know if you already decided witch components are you going to release for 2016 R4.

Comment: You can check the newly released Roadmap - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/

Comment: Hi Petyo, now we have first final version of kendo for angular but no context menu. Am i right? if so...Any eta here? So thanks.

Comment: Kendo has a new menu package but it still contains no context menu. I published my custom "combine kendo menu and kendo popup to context menu" here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@40three/kendo-angular-extensions perhaps it saves someone some time until there's an "official" version.